# how do I put an endpoint in ranorex and get this answer?

Tags: ranorex

https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random

```
{
    "category": null,
    "icon_url": "https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png",
    "id": "_eLD9PRxS9-hNbuTfF7-oA",
    "url": "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/_eLD9PRxS9-hNbuTfF7-oA",
    "value": "Mother Teresa said Chuck Norris was the only man she ever wanted to marry."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible by using the Ranorex API.
There is already a similar feature request on the [Ranorex UserVoice](https://uservoice.ranorex.com/forums/150109-ideas-to-improve-ranorex/suggestions/20380744-can-we-have-the-feature-to-pass-the-instance-of-th). You can vote for the feature, or create a new one there. 
Or you can ask Chuck Norris. I'm sure he will find a solution ;-)